# Which algorithm is used ProtonMail SRP session IDs?

Tags: protonmail

Having read up on a bunch of different SRP implementations I understand that the session ID is generally not random, although it’s missing from the documented SRP write up they did. Anyone know how theirs work? It’s 32 hex characters long.